# Detect Double Tap on UITabbarControler Item to scroll table view up

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I using TableView under Tab Bar
My requirement is to scroll table view up when user double tap on tab bar item for selected view controller

this is my code

```
 func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
{

    if tabBarController.viewControllers!.index(of: viewController) == 0 {
        if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController{
            if let streamController = navigationController.viewControllers.last as? StreamViewController
            {
                streamController.tableViewStream.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: false)

            }
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

But this is causing to scroll table up when user even single tap on item, due to this I am note able to retain scroll position.

So what I want is

1.If user scroll the table and go on another tab and come back again by single tap scroll position should remain same

2.If user tap double any time on tab tab bar item the list should be scroll to top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code i would add checking if this view controller is already selected

```
if tabBarController.viewControllers!.index(of: viewController) == 0 {

    if self.selectedIndex != 0 { return true }

    if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController{
        if let streamController = navigationController.viewControllers.last as? StreamViewController
        {
            streamController.tableViewStream.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: false)

        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: thanks its solve problem not exactly with double tap but if I tap on tab bar item if I am already on 0 index

Comment: i tried, when user move to another tab and again return to 0 tab, its scroll again.